# Работа с файлами в директории сайта

Tags: javascript

Есть такой отрывок ЯваСкрипта, который вставляет картинки в таблицу из папки `content`.
имена картинок имеют вид `0.jpg`, `1.jpg`...`9.jpg`

```js
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", "content/" + i + ".jpg");
}
```

Есть ли возможность заставить ЯваСкрипт заставить посчитать файлы картинок в папке `content` и установить количество итераций в соответствии с ним?
Например, так:

```js
var imgCount = .... //какой-то код
for (var i=0; i<imgCount; i++) {
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", "content/" + i + ".jpg");
}
```

P.S. Серверная часть отсутствует. Должен получиться локальный фотоальбомчик-презентация.

Comment: Ввиду защиты сайта, посчитать нельзя, но, можно перехватить свойства OnComplate и OnError, или проверять статус картинки. Когда будет получен статус ошибки (404 NotFound) - остановить "цикл".

Comment: можно заставить PHP-скрипт сосчитать картинки в папке и даже их имена, а потом передать это все в js.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что серверная часть отсутствует. Исправил свой вопрос.

Comment: нет, нельзя.!!!

Comment: @Grundy, никак)

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант можно использовать `API файлов`.
Далее все взято из этой [статьи](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

> **Выбор файлов с помощью формы ввода данных**
>
> Самый простой способ загрузки файлов – использование стандартного элемента . JavaScript возвращает список выбранных объектов File в виде объекта FileList. Вот пример использования атрибута multiple для выбора сразу нескольких файлов:

```js
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  //alert('Great success! All the File APIs are supported.');
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(), '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Таким образом можно получить имена нужных файлов, добавить их в массив или любым другим способ уже их обрабатывать и показывать.

Comment: Какое отношение это имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov `локальный фотоальбомчик-презентация`

Comment: @slippyk, в вопросе нет ничего про ручное выделение файлов

Comment: @slippyk Ну так файлы-то ему надо с диска взять, а не запросить у пользователя

Comment: Файлы руками добавляются в папку `content`. Наверно придется писать какой-то генератор html+JS, который будет создавать страничку и запускать браузер.